# Convert top-posting email to bottom-posting in Thunderbird

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, email-client

I would like to convert long email conversations from top-posting style to the bottom-posting style so I can paste it to a web page and other people can easily read it from the start to the end and not vice versa.

So far I was looking for a Thunderbird plugin but without any success. I would accept anything what will do the job (script or standalone application), preferably on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a Thinderbird addon called [Posting Style Enforcer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/posting-style-enforcer/), that converts all messages transparently.

(I know, two years too late)

Answer (score 1):

Found a C-language program which should do this job on http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=131550.

- I was able to compile it without any problem
- It works. I tried the following

  cat top-posted.txt | ./top2bottom > bottom-posted.txt

cat top-posted.txt

```
 
    No problem. 6pm it is then. --Jim

    At 10.01am Wednesday, Danny wrote:
    > Whoa! I need to email a report at 5:30.
    > Could you push it back an hour? --Danny
    >
    > At 9.40am Wednesday, Jim wrote:
    >
    >> I'm going to suspend the mail service for approx. thirty
    >> minutes tonight, starting at 5pm. --Jim
```

cat bottom-posted.txt

```
    >> I'm going to suspend the mail service for approx. thirty
    >> minutes tonight, starting at 5pm. --Jim
    > Whoa! I need to email a report at 5:30.
    > Could you push it back an hour? --Danny
    >
    > At 9.40am Wednesday, Jim wrote:
    >
    No problem. 6pm it is then. --Jim

    At 10.01am Wednesday, Danny wrote:
```